# cannot select option from multiple select after removing old options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.jquery to convert my select to multiple select. When I remove the current options from my select field and load the new ones, I am not able to select the newly added options.

I debugged and noticed that at following line from Chosen.Jquery.js the selected option is unselected.

```
  if (this.is_multiple || this.form_field.selectedIndex !== this.current_selectedIndex) {  
      this.form_field_jq.trigger("change", {
        'selected': this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value
      });
    }
```

I execute following code after I remove the options from the list.

```
$('#partnerCasteId').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

I just noticed that liszt:updated option is not present in the Chosen.jquery.
Do I need to get a different version?
Please help

Comment: please show a working snippet

Comment: This is the example. https://jsfiddle.net/ParagCool/bsf877ko/9/

Comment: Please help me as I am stuck.

Comment: I found the issue. I was calling same chosen function for both the drop downs.